# Blinking NSButton with Core Animation

Tags: core-animation, nsbutton

I've got an `NSButton` called `_indicatorButton` with a PNG image (basically a green LED light as PNG set with setImage:) without border and text. I'm trying to make it "flash" with the following code:

```
- (void)animateButton
{
    NSLog(@"Animating…");
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    [animation setDuration:0.3f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction
                                  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [animation setRepeatCount:20000];

    [_indicatorButton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
}
```

…but nothing happens. The method gets called and the link in the XIB is OK, since changing the image on the button programmatically works fine.

Any hints why it doesn't blink at all?

Comment: What version of OS X? Is you view layer backed?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Mountain Lion. What do you mean with "backed"?

Comment: You should read [the documentation for `wantsLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer:)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks it works now ;-) Could you add an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For backwards compatibility, views on OS X don't use Core Animation layers as their backing store by default. The reason nothing is happening is likely that layer of your button is nil.

You can tell your view that it should be layer-backed using `myView.wantsLayer = YES;`. Please read [the documentation for `wantsLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer%3a).